# why my div width 100% not working even I use new class

Tags: css, wordpress

I have submenu with default class `.sub-menu` with fixed width 270px. and I have one has custom class `.sub-menu-custom`. But it still use the old class with `270px` even i don't put it.

[image]

even on inspect element, there is no 270px

[image]

and this is my code.

```
#custom-menu-news-and-events .sub-menu-custom {
    position: absolute;
    left: initial;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

you can see my site here:
https://gcm.edu.ph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as expected and setting the width to 100% of the parent element (li).
Change your .sub-menu-custom to read like the others:

```
#custom-menu-news-and-events .sub-menu-custom {
    position: absolute;
    left: initial;
    right: 0;
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be full width on screen, not 270px on my custom class. this 270px is default width for all submenu except one I created `.sub-menu-custom` so it can get full 100% width but it's not working.\

Comment: thanks a lot, `position: fixed` fix for me. that `270px` is change to `width: 100%`